# Need a good source for AT&T Assembly Syntax

Tags: assembly, att

I'm looking for sources to study assembly with AT&T syntax(NOT Intel), any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find resources to learn inline assembly in C using AT&T syntax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749056/where-can-i-find-resources-to-learn-inline-assembly-in-c-using-att-syntax)

Comment: @Alex not really, many tutorials are about inline assembly but few are about actual assembly programming. I'm actually experiencing this problem as well.

Comment: @Hawken: the inline and non-inline syntax are very similar. For general assembly programming learning there are many different sites and resources that have little to do with syntax.

Comment: @Alex sorry if my comment expresses some of my own frustration then; I had trouble finding any AT&T syntax programs that were not inline/ or run with the help of the C Libraries. Learning from inline C or or programs starting from the C Lib, kept me from writing actual assembly using `_main` and `ret` instead of `_start:` and `int $0x80`. Sorry if my comment was merely expressing my anger at inline Asm/ asm derived from C.

Answer (score 2):

You an find a lot of assembler sources in the linux kernel in the *arch* subdirectory. For the common x86 processors, every file ending with `.S` in /usr/src/linux/arch/x86 is a usually well documented assembler source.

If you don't have the source on your box, you can download them at http://kernel.org.

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend "Programming from Ground Up" which can be found at: http://savannah.spinellicreations.com//pgubook/ProgrammingGroundUp-1-0-booksize.pdf

It was great help.