# Sources for AT&T syntax instruction format

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86

I am looking for a decent source on how AT&T syntax assembler instructions are formed (the syntax used by gcc inline asm).

There are some semi decent ones covering gcc such as [the DJGPP guide](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/brennan/brennan_att_inline_djgpp.html) or [the GCC inline asm howto](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html), but none of these describe the syntax detailed enough so one could deduct all instructions' formats using an opcode guide written for the Intel syntax.

I see there are already questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749056/where-can-i-find-resources-to-learn-inline-assembly-in-c-using-att-syntax) on the subject, but without suitable answers.

Most particularly currently I am stumped about how a three operand imul should be formatted. The only pointer I could find on this is [this forum post](http://forums.anandtech.com/archive/index.php/t-2110757.html), with apparently just as stumped people as me on this matter.

(OK, it is true I could try and see, but really there should be some proper docs out in the wild for these types of things which I just can't find)

Comment: How about this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776570/is-there-a-complete-x86-assembly-language-reference-that-uses-att-syntax

Comment: Drat, then mine is a dupe :p. However that still does not document the operand order of a 3 op. imul! :lol:

Comment: Also note you can switch `gcc` and `gas` to intel if you like that better. Generally operand order is simply reversed.

Comment: @Jester: and you get rid of those pesky `%` characters! And ... well, let's just say that I prefer the Intel syntax.